# I Can't change my password

Tags: password

I can not change my password to slide or no password, it says it is due to administrator policies but i have disabled all apps from there, What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

That is because of credential storage. Go to settings--> storage and clear the credential storage. Reboot your device and now you will be able to set lock screen to swipe or no password.